# Unable to connect to excel file as data source

Tags: c#, excel, odbc, oledb

I'm working on an old (ca. 2004) ASP.NET 2.0 application. A feature was request to allow users to upload data via an excel file. Having done this before (albeit with newer technologies), I figured it would be simple.

The problem(s) I'm having are that I am unable to use an excel file as a datasource, regardless of what provider I use.

I am able to connect to a SQL Server database just fine.

The first issue I had was when I was trying to connect via OleDB. Each time I tried to connect, I received an error.

I'm running 64-bit W7, and have 32-bit office installed (unable to change, work laptop).

The connection strings I tried are

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; DataSource='{0}'; Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; DataSource='{0}'; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'    Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; DataSource='{0}'; Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'
Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; DataSource='{0}'; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'    Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; DataSource='{0}'; Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'
Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; DataSource='{0}'; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'
```

The error I received was

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

I did some research and found several different ways people have tried solving this, from downloading the 2007 access drivers, the 2010 ones, adding it via `C:\Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe` and building the application in x86 mode (which doesn't run anyways, not quite sure why though). All of which resulted in the same error.

I then tried connecting via ODBC with the following connection string

```
Driver={{Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}};DBQ='{0}';
```

and then I got a new error, namely

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Doing some research, I ended up back at the same resolutions as before.

One interesting thing that I did note, is that when I ran `odbcad32.exe` from the `SysWOW64` folder and `System32` folder, I had different results. When I ran it from the x64 folder, I saw under `User DSN` both Excel files and Access database. I added both to the `System DSN` just to be safe, and saw that under the `Drivers` tab, they were also there.

However, when I ran it under the System32 folder, I see them under the `User DSN` tab like before, but I'm unable to Configure them. When I try, I get the following error:

```
The setup routines for the Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb) ODBC driver could not be found. Please reinstall the driver.
Errors Found: The specified DSN contains and architecture mismatch between the Driver and the Application
```

If I try to add it under the `System DSN` tab, the only ones available are

- ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
- SQL Server
- SQL Server Native Client 11.0

And the Excel/Access drivers do not show up under the `Drivers` tab, only those 3.

What else can I try? I am also not able to use third-party libraries.

Comment: have a look at EPPLUS, but I'm not sure if it works with older .net applications

Comment: @katz I've updated the OP. I'm not able to use third-party libraries in the current version.